# Unable to perform divide operation in BigDecimal Java without rounding off

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have two Big Decimal values and I am performing below calculation :

```
Formula = 850 * (a/b)
where a = 0.6, b = 11
```

Expected value according to calculator: 46.36

whereas by using `BigDecimal.divide(value,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` formula,original value of `(a/b=0.0545454545)` becomes 0.05 and ultimately calculated value becomes `= 42.5 (850*(0.05))`

Without rounding off the value to 0.05, How can I get the expected value?
Please suggest if there is any other way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? In particular, make sure you round only at the very end. Also, if you are going to round anyway and have intermediate results that cannot be expressed with decimals, maybe you can just use `double` instead of `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimal` cannot represent numbers with a non-terminating decimal expansion (like 0.05454545..). That's why you have to specify the rounding mode to not get an `ArithmeticException`.

However, you can specify an arbitary number of decimal numbers using the precision parameter. Because you have set it to 2, it will round it down to 2 decimals (hence you get 0.05).

You could therefore just increase the scale of your division operation:

```
a.divide(b, 50, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to rearrange the formula.
You can change **850 * (a / b)** to **(850 * a) / b**.
(Do the multiplication first followed by the division)

```java
BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.multiply(a,1,RoundingMode.HALF_UP),2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Replace `1` by the number of digits after the decimal in `a` and `2` by the required number of digits after the decimal in the answer.